# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'pluralization' in undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to achieve inheritance using the discriminator, as shown in the [Mongoose API documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.discriminator). However, I keep getting the following error:

> C:\Code\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:364   if
>   (!('pluralization' in schema.options)) schema.options.pluralization =
>   thi
>    ^
>       TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'pluralization' in undefined
>       at Mongoose.model (C:\Code\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:364:34)

Here's the code that causes the error above; my attempt to extend the mongoose Schema class to make my base schema:

```
var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

function ResourceSchema() {
  Schema.apply(this, arguments);

  this.add({
    title: String
  });
}
util.inherits(ResourceSchema, Schema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Resource', ResourceSchema);
```

I have also tried setting the collection name in the last line, but that didn't help.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Resource', ResourceSchema, 'resources');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to create a model off a schema *class*, not a schema *instance*.

Use this instead:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Resource', new ResourceSchema());
```

This is analogous to how you normally create a model:

```
var schema = new Schema({ ... }); // or, in your case, ResourceSchema
var model  = mongoose.model('Model', schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `userSchema.js` file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
})

const User=mongoose.model('USER',userSchema)
module.exports =User
```